# Getting an array of properties for an object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, object

Is it possible to get an array of all of an object's properties in Objective C? Basically, what I want to do is something like this:

```
- (void)save {
   NSArray *propertyArray = [self propertyNames];
   for (NSString *propertyName in propertyArray) {
      [self doSomethingCoolWithValue:[self valueForKey:propertyName]];
   }
}
```

Is this possible? It seems like it should be, but I can't figure out what method my  `propertyNames` up there should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some more digging, and found what I wanted in the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW24). Here's how I've implemented the what I wanted to do in my original question, drawing heavily from Apple's sample code:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)save {
    id currentClass = [self class];
    NSString *propertyName;
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(currentClass, &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property)];
        [self doSomethingCoolWithValue:[self valueForKey:propertyName]];
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone else looking for a way to access the names of an object's properties programatically.

Comment: If you search for `class_copyPropertyList` this questions has been answered several times on StackOverflow in various forms, but unless you know the answer already, if hard to know what to search for... ;)

Comment: you need free(properties) at the end.

Comment: @JohnBiesnecker `stringWithCString:` is deprecated. I'm using `stringWithCString:encoding:` with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding now. Just a note. :)

Answer (score 2):

dont forget

```
free(properties);
```

after the loop or you will get a leak. The apple documentation is clear:

> An array of pointers of type objc_property_t describing the properties
>   declared by the class. Any properties declared by superclasses are not
>   included. The array contains *outCount pointers followed by a NULL
>   terminator. **You must free the array with free()**.